# Can I pass arguments to a gulp task?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, gulp

I'm using gulp in Visual Studio, as a client-side build tool *only*.

I have lots of tasks which are common across various projects, so I moved them to separate files, and reference them in a project's `gulpfile.js` as follows:

```
require("../path/to/task/files/fooCommon.js");  // has a task called "fooCommon"
```

And then in the `gulpfile.js` I wrap it in a task:

```
gulp.task("foo", ["fooCommon"], function () { });
```

This works nicely, and I can reuse common tasks across projects.

BUT, some tasks require configurations which are only accessible in `gulpfile.js` - *how can I pass them as arguments to a task?*

Comment: Is there any reason the common logic needs to actually register the tasks? Why not export something like `module.exports = function(gulp, config){` and have that register the tasks like `require("../path/to/task/files/fooCommon.js")(gulp, {...})`

Comment: @loganfsmyth Unsure what you mean. Though if I'm understanding you correctly, the gulpfile.js won't know about those tasks as they weren't registered. And also, only the gulpfile has access to the config for the project, those external task files have no knowledge of anything other than a single task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things come to mind. The first would be that instead of `fooCommon.js` creating tasks, it could create something usable as a `gulp` plugin, so then to use it, you just pass your config arguments to the plugin. If that doesn't fit well in this case, then you can move your task logic into a wrapper function, e.g.

#### fooCommon.js

```
module.exports = function(gulp, config){
    gulp.task("fooCommon", function () {
        // Use the config here
    });
};
```

#### Gulpfile

```
// Define whatever config you need
var gulp = require('gulp');

var config = {...}

var taskCreator = require('../path/to/task/files/fooCommon.js');

// Call the function in 'fooCommon.js', which will be passed the config, and
// will create all the tasks you have in common.
taskCreator(gulp, config);

// Register a task depending on the task created by the exported function.
gulp.task("foo", ["fooCommon"], function () { });
```

Comment: This works well. Not sure you even need the last line, depending on your setup.

Comment: @hbob Cool. You are right about the last line, I just misunderstood your example, I thought you were saying you also had a body in the `foo` task. When defining a task, you can leave the function off entirely, e.g. `gulp.task("foo", ["fooCommon"]);`

Comment: Thank you, this is a great way to reuse a task so you could use the same tasks at the command line with app 'X' as app 'Y', just passing in an additional parameter at the command line.

Comment: However, this solution would run into problems if you were trying to build multiple apps at once with the same asynchronous tasks.  If the tasks are asynchronous, you'll have a hard time figuring out whether task Foo for app X is completed before you need to load in the config for App Y.  I have a hard time figuring out how to create a truly dynamic, reusable gulp task without the ability to take parameters.