# gulp.start how to pass parameters?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I'm building a simple gulp watch task,

```
gulp.task('serve', function () {
    console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
});

gulp.task('default', [


], function () {
    gulp.watch([
        './index.js',
        './views/**/*.pug'
    ], function (event) {
        gulp.start('serve');
    });
});
```

I want to pass `event` object in `gulp.start` and catch in `serve` task.

Comment: You can't pass arguments to gulp tasks, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306844/can-i-pass-arguments-to-a-gulp-task.  However, can't you just create a global variable outside of any task, set it in the gulp.watch return(event)  function and then access it in the 'serve' task?  And gulp.start is deprecated: see https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/505

Comment: And see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670209/gulp-how-to-pass-parameters-from-watch-to-tasks which has a possible solution for you.  In the function(event) call a function (not gulp.start) like serve(event) and in that make your gulp.src stream.

Comment: Yeah, I found it useful...! Thanks.